# In Silverlight how do you set the HeaderStyle of a dynamic DataGridColumn

Tags: silverlight, dynamic, datagridcolumn

I have a data grid and I am dynamically adding columns to this grid from my ViewModel.  The user has a settings dialog where they can manage which columns appear in this DataGrid.  The problem I'm running into is that I don't know how to set a HeaderStyle on one of these DataGridColumns that are created in my ViewModel.

The most basic version of this would be to be able to add a tooltip to the DataGridColumnHeader for these dynamic columns.  Note that these columns are not being defined in XAML because of their dynamic nature.  Most of the columns are data-driven and thus aren't known at compile time.

*Bonus Points* for showing how to add a button to this style and how to setup its click or command property so that I can remove the column from the grid (envision an x image on a button in the column header, when I click this I want to remove the column.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can assign a HeaderStyle in code like this:-

```
        Style headerStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGridColumnHeader));
        headerStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(ToolTipService.ToolTipProperty, "Hello World"));

        yourDynamicColumn.HeaderStyle = headerStyle;
```

Comment: Do you know of any way that I could set to delete button?  I had actually discovered this method for setting the tooltip, but it doesn't support adding UI elements to the column header.

Comment: @Boushley:  Its much harder then it ought to be.  One approach would be completely replace the Template for the DataGridColumnHeader.  But even then you'll have to find a way to bind the button click to the operation you would want to perform.

Comment: Right, that seems to be what I'm discovering.  It seems like I would have to jump through a lot of hoops to get a button in there... and when I did binding it to the right thing wouldn't really work :/